# Where to Hash User Passwords in a API Gateway Microservices Pattern

Tags: security, microservices, api-gateway

The title pretty much sums it up. I'm breaking apart a monolith and struggling with some of the smaller design choices in the microservice world.

I have a gateway API that is a reverse proxy to all my other services. I'm trying to keep all the services as self-contained as possible but I'm wondering what the best practice is when dealing with a user's password. Is it:

1. Better to keep the user's service completely contained and send the password between the gateway and the service in plaintext.
2. Hash the password immediately upon getting to the gateway and only send the hash to the service while adding a little more coupling between the services.

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: The purpose of hashing the password is to protect it at rest. In transit, it is protected by encryption. Hash the password in the service.

Comment: @JohnWu This is a great point that didn't even cross my mind. That is exactly what I'll do. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Generally the pattern is not to actually send the password between microservices, but rather send an authorization token that asserts authorization.  JWT is typical in this case.  The assertion can include user information, but need not have a password involved, which is more secure for everyone.

There is a new service introduced that checks the user's username and password, and exchanges those for a secured token, that includes signed metadata like the user id, access levels, and possibly other information.

Details at jwt.io or search anywhere for OAuth2.

Comment: This is probably true, but only if the mentioned API gateway is actually capable of doing _authentication_, and is not instead relaying authentication to another service. The latter seems to be the case as far as I understood.

Comment: Untrue!  JWT is a self-contained authenticated identity exchange. Some other service can do the auth, and any service can decode and rely on it.

Comment: This is not what I meant, and maybe I misunderstood the OP. I was under the assumption that the broken-into-microservices original application includes some authentication service. Thus, the API gateway must contact this very service for authentication. _Of course_, JWT can be used here, after successful authentication. That is, the authentication service would issue JWT. Nevertheless, for initial authentication, the authentication service needs to be provided with the username and password.
But as I said, maybe I misunderstood the original question.

Comment: ... so thats a different use case than what you wrote. You're talking about _authorization_, while I was talking about _authentication_, which I thought was the point of the OP.

Comment: Its' always challenging to decode a full architecture from a few statements.  I guess the important point is that some kind of token must be passed, and most efficently the token should be trustable by the recipient without needing to make an external call to some other service.  JWT is an easy way to do that, regardless of how the tokens are generated.

Comment: Taking the question at face value, you should hash passwords in the same way you would hash any other password. :/